# Mixing blender with java

Tags: java, gis, blender

I'm new to blender and i'm currently working on a GIS project...I've created a realistic 3d model of a city using openstreetmap(done with success) but the main thing that i'm stuck is on how to implement this 3d model in my java application. I've done some research but all that i'm getting are for python related plateforms. Any ideas/theories are most welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use Blender models in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532988/how-do-i-use-blender-models-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

First you must find a java library for manipulating/displaying 3D objects and Graphics, then just export your model into a supported file type. like .obj or .3DS.

There are many Java libraries for 3D graphics manipulation.
Such as JavaFX 3D https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/javafx-3d-graphics.htm